# operating system first fit algorithm

Tags: algorithm, memory-management, operating-system

This is a free space table

```
+--------+-------+
|address | size  | 
|   28   |  11   |
|   21   |  19   |
+--------+-------+
```

the following data enters: `11, 5, 7`

I need to place the each data in the right place using first fit algorithm.

Am I doing this right?

(step 1) 11 will be placed at address 28 at size 11

(step 2) 5 will be placed at address 21 by dividing 19 into two pieces, so 14 is created (new partition)

(step 3) 7 will be placed at address 21 at size 14 that is creates in step (2)

Comment: May I ask which operating system uses such kind of memory allocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks right, except the 7-long entry doesn't go at address 21 because that's where 5 is going to be by then. The 7-long entry will probably go at address 21+5=26. And that if the search in the table is conducted in the order the table is shown or from higher to lower addresses. Also, the last step produces a new partition as well.

If, OTOH, the search is conducted in the opposite direction, then the result is different.

On a second thought, this all doesn't look right. How come 21+19=40 > 28? Or are these the addresses of the end and not the beginning of the free partitions??? But then 28-11=17 < 21.

Does not compute.

Something's wrong or missing in your assignment.